# Know if the device has moved and register gps coords

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm doing an app and I want to check on internet some information, but I only want to do it if the device has been moved *X* meters.
For example, if the user has moved 300 meters, make a call to the server, if not, do nothing. But I think I can't launch a service listening all the time the gps coords and calculating the distance, because the battery will draing to fast.

And my question is: There are any way that Android start a service o send a broadcast warning me that the gps coord has changed X meters?

Currently I have an AlarmManager and every 30 minutes gets the gps coords, but I need more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates();` method; you can specify the minimum amount of time in seconds an update should be sent, and the minimum amount of meters before updating.

Should look something like this:

> //in milliseconds
>   private final int MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 5000;
>
> //in meters
>   private final int MINIMUM_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1;
>
> ```
> LocationManager lManager =(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
> LocationListener = listener = new LocationListener() {
>
>           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {           
> }
>
>           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
>           }
>
>
>           public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
>           }
>
>           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
>           }
>
>       };
>
> lManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES, listener);
> ```

This creates a `LocationManager` with the specified location provider (GPS or Network), a specified amount of seconds and a specified amount of meters. The locationmanager sends the updates to the `LocationListener. The onLocationChanged gets called whenever an update is received. The bestProvider variable can be found by using LocationManager.getBestProvider(); and the Criteria class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm passing 0 value on MINIMUM_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES, I think your solution should be work.